# Making a function in a c++ project with clr support to be interopable

Tags: c#, interop, c++-cli, clr

In my C# project, I wish to interop a function that is defined in a clr project.
I usually use

```
 __declspec( dllexport )
```

in the function definition in the case of a native c++ project. How do I make the function interopable for a clr project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the `ref` class `public` and the method you want to call `public`.  Then reference the project from your C# project.

Comment: That works but I can't do that because the clr project uses that c# project as a reference. So if I do this, it will lead to a cyclic dependency. So I went with interoping, as it would not need me to use the clr project as a reference

Comment: How is that supposed to be obvious from the question?  Clearly you'll have to break your C# project in two, separating out the declarations that your C++/CLI project needs.  Or move them to the C++/CLI project.

Comment: Or use interfaces or delegates, which allow the C++/CLI code to conform to a signature established in C#, such that C# can call it.